# Negative Boost in Solr (bq vs bf)

Tags: solr, lucene, solr-boost

In `Solr8` I am trying to execute a negative boost query using bf tag.

`Solr8` bf query for a negative boost. 
Migrating from `Solr6` to `Solr8`, so updating negative boost as follows:

```
Solr6: bq=catConfidence:("0")^-100.0

Solr8: bq=(**:** -catConfidence:"0")^100.0
```

This works fine for bq tag. 
I want it as part of bf tag,

`bf=(*:* -catConfidence:"0")^100.0` , this is not working.

As a negative boost is not working in `Solr8`, I tried

```
bf= (*:* -catConfidence)^10.0
```

Any advice on how to write bf for negative boosting.

Comment: The `bq` and `bf` arguments are not used in the same way. `bf` is for _boost functions_, while `bq` is for _boost queries_. You're using a query, so `bq` would be the correct argument to use. What is your goal by using `bf` instead?

Comment: I am trying to execute this function : scale(catConfidence,0,1)^-10.0. For this, I am getting the error as " boost must be a positive float, got -10.0".

Answer (score 1):

Negative boost functions are not supported by Solr.

A workaround is to reverse the local score given by the function itself so that you can apply a regular (positive) boost on it.

For example, this query :

```
bf=scale(catConfidence,0,1)^-10.0
```

would become :

```
bf=div(1,scale(catConfidence,0.000001,1)))^10.0
```

(I changed the scale min to prevent division by 0).